# SELinux file path context not working with regex

Tags: linux, selinux, regex

I've reformatted for readability based on suggestions in the comments.

I have a RADIUS server that uses google authenticator, and SELinux is blocking RADIUS from accessing the .google_authenticator files in the user home directories (these are also winbind users, with home dirs in `/home/API`).  I tried to give it access by building the following policy files:

```
$ cat ./google-authenticator.fc 
/home/API(/.*)?/\.google_authenticator      gen_context(system_u:object_r:radiusd_google_authenticator_t,s0)
$ cat ./google-authenticator.te
policy_module(radiusd_google_authenticator, 0.0.10)

require {
  type radiusd_t;
  type user_home_dir_t;
  type admin_home_t;
}

type radiusd_google_authenticator_t;

role object_r types radiusd_google_authenticator_t;

allow radiusd_t radiusd_google_authenticator_t:file { rename create unlink rw_file_perms };

files_type(radiusd_google_authenticator_t)
filetrans_pattern(radiusd_t, user_home_dir_t, radiusd_google_authenticator_t, file, ".google_authenticator")
filetrans_pattern(radiusd_t, admin_home_t, radiusd_google_authenticator_t, file, ".google_authenticator")
```

Installing these shows the path in `semanage fcontext -l`, but it doesn't work:

```
 $ sudo semanage fcontext -l | grep google_authenticator
 /home/API(/.*)?/\.google_authenticator             all files          system_u:object_r:radiusd_google_authenticator_t:s0 
 $ matchpathcon /home/API/tcr/.google_authenticator
 /home/API/tcr/.google_authenticator    unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_t:s0
```

Weirdly enough, when I change it so that the path matches exactly (even with the escaped period), it works:

```
$ sudo semanage fcontext -l | grep google_authenticator
/home/API/tcr/\.google_authenticator               all files          system_u:object_r:radiusd_google_authenticator_t:s0 
$ matchpathcon /home/API/tcr/.google_authenticator
/home/API/tcr/.google_authenticator system_u:object_r:radiusd_google_authenticator_t:s0
```

Even weirder, the regex works when, as suggested in Iain's answer, I add the path directly with semanage instead of the policy files (removing the policy path first so there is no conflict):

```
$ sudo semanage fcontext -l | grep google_authenticator
$ matchpathcon /home/API/tcr/.google_authenticator
/home/API/tcr/.google_authenticator unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_t:s0
$ sudo semanage fcontext -a -t radiusd_google_authenticator_t '/home/API(/.*)?/\.google_authenticator'
$ sudo semanage fcontext -l | grep google_authenticator
/home/API(/.*)?/\.google_authenticator             all files          system_u:object_r:radiusd_google_authenticator_t:s0 
$ matchpathcon /home/API/tcr/.google_authenticator
/home/API/tcr/.google_authenticator system_u:object_r:radiusd_google_authenticator_t:s0
```

I've also tried various setups using HOME_DIR, but had no luck there either.

Comment: Take a look at the output of `semanage fcontext -l` for examples.

Comment: I've been looking at that output.  My policy is the only one that references `/home` at all.  The other pattern examples I show are actually copied directly out of `semanage fcontext -l`

Comment: Your question could probably do with a bit of cleaning up, it's messy and even more confusing now. State what you want to do - show what you've tried etc

Comment: @Iain You're right.  I've reformatted for readability.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using

```
HOME_DIR/\.google_authenticator -- gen_context(system_u:object_r:radiusd_google_authenticator_t,s0)
```

Instead. Home directories aren't necessarily in /home and this acts as a macro when you rebuild policy.

**EDIT**

So I checked the source code and it provides the following text which probably indicates whats going on here.

```
label_file.c
680     /*
681      * Check for matching specifications in reverse order, so that
682      * the last matching specification is used.
683      */
```

Regex that match last, win. The SELinux library is using the following order of file lookups to match:

```
/etc/selinux/targeted/contexts/files/file_contexts.subs_dist
/etc/selinux/targeted/contexts/files/file_contexts.subs
/etc/selinux/targeted/contexts/files/file_contexts
/etc/selinux/targeted/contexts/files/file_contexts.homedirs
/etc/selinux/targeted/contexts/files/file_contexts.local
```

The matching regex that wins in your case is this one:

```
grep user_home_t /etc/selinux/targeted/contexts/files/file_contexts.homedirs
/home/[^/]+/.+  user_u:object_r:user_home_t:s0
```

By adding the entry as a local context, it is fetched from this file instead: `/etc/selinux/targeted/contexts/files/file_contexts.local` which appears *after* the file that matches at the moment.

So, in order to fix this (which is basically a little bit of a hack) you can add the entry as a local override.

Alternatively I tried adding this as a HOME_DIR override (like I originally suggested, but using audio_home_t to test the principal) doing the following:

```
HOME_DIR/(tcr)?/\.google_authenticator          --      gen_context(system_u:object_r:audio_home_t)
```

This worked for me, given it added the entry to the later files and the 'last regex won' when I did that.

It actually changed the regex to this in the file:

```
grep tcr /etc/selinux/targeted/contexts/files/*
/etc/selinux/targeted/contexts/files/file_contexts.homedirs:/home/[^/]+/(tcr)?/\.google_authenticator   --  user_u:object_r:audio_home_t:s0
```

I would suggest trying the HOME_DIR option first (which is the actual way in policy you should implement it) or alternatively use a local override.

Comment: I was nervous about doing that because they are network users, sourced through winbind, and not local.  Using that in my fc file doesn't seem to work at all.

Comment: Wow, that's a fantastic bit of digging you've done.  Thank you.  I'll investigate this and award the bounty if it comes up fruitful.

Comment: I've tested this by using an empty `.fc` file and adding the context via `semanage fcontext -a -t radiusd_google_authenticator_t '/home/API(/.*)?/\.google_authenticator'`, which I'd done before and worked, but now, thanks to your answer, I know the context, and I know **why** this method was working when the policy wasn't (it's added to the `file_contexts.local` file).  I still don't know the proper way to give a policy higher priority than the existing `homedirs` one, but I now know why it's happening the way it happens, and how to deploy this properly.  Thank you very much.

Comment: I'll award the bounty in a day or two, since there is apparently a wait associated with bounty awards.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to to but if it's to have a wildcard `*` after API so that for example

```
/home/API/one/.google_authenticator
/home/API/two/.google_authenticator
...
```

all have type `radiusd_google_authenticator_t` then this seems to work

```
sudo semanage fcontext -a -t mysqld_db_t  "/home/API(/.*)?/.google_authenticator"
```

Note I have used mysqld_db_t as I don't have radiusd_google_authenticator_t

```
matchpathcon /home/API/one/.google_authenticator
/home/API/one/.google_authenticator     system_u:object_r:mysqld_db_t:s0
matchpathcon /home/API/two/.google_authenticator
/home/API/two/.google_authenticator     system_u:object_r:mysqld_db_t:s0
```

Comment: There's something odd going on here.  I have that line in my list, and it works when added via semanage fcontext, but not when added via the .pp file.  I've added an edit at the bottom of the OP with the extra information.